# Where can I ask this question about "Chrome indexedDB"?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Where can I ask this question about Chrome-IndexedDB?

> I have a disk space issue and see that IndexedDB of Chrome has 20GB.
>   How can I limit the size of IndexedDB?

Answer (score 0):

Questions about Web browsers and their features are generally on-topic at [Super User](https://superuser.com).

In fact, that's where [your question from Web Apps was migrated](https://superuser.com/q/1243793/1100), so don't re-ask it.